# How can i read multiple lines in file.csv

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures, file-handling

I want to read information from the file but can only read the first line in the file:

```
int deserialize(Contact **head) {
    FILE *file = fopen("contacts.csv", "rb");
    Contact *temp = (Contact *)malloc(5 * sizeof(Contact));
    *head = (Contact *)malloc(50 * sizeof(Contact));
    if (file == NULL)
        return 0;

    while (*head != NULL &&
           (fscanf(file, "%d,%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%d\n",
                   &((*head)->id), &((*head)->firstName),
                   &((*head)->middleName), &((*head)->lastName),
                   &((*head)->company), &((*head)->phone),
                   &((*head)->company), &((*head)->address),
                   &((*head)->birthday), &((*head)->website),
                   &((*head)->note), &((*head)->status))) > 0)
    {
        printf(" head: %s\n", (*head)->firstName);
        *head = (*head)->next;
    }
    fclose(file);
    return 1;
}
```

My **file.csv**:

```
4,d,d,d,,,,,,,,0
3,c,c,c,,,,,,,,0
2,b,b,b,,,,,,,,0
1,a,a,a,,,,,,,,0
```

my output:

```
head: d
```

Comment: Please edit your question to provide a [mre].

Comment: Do you really want to company copied from two different places to the same field?

Comment: The use of the address-of operator (`&`) on the variadic arguments associated with the `%[` is a code smell. `%[` expects a `char *` (a pointer to the first character of a sufficiently sized buffer), not a `char **` or `char (*)[N]`. Additionally, failing to provide a [*maximum field width*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) with `%[` leaves it susceptible to buffer overflows ([Undefined Behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior)).

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple problems in the posted code:

- you have a memory leak in case of `fopen` failure
- opening the text file in binary mode is not recommended: you will need to handle legacy line termination sequences explicitly. Better use text mode (`"r"`) and let the library handle them.
- you allocate an array of 50 contacts for `head` to point to, but this is not a linked list.
- `*head = (*head)->next` has undefined behavior as `(*head)->next` was never set. You could instead store the next entry to `(*head)[1]` or use an actual pointer instead of a double pointer.
- `%[^,]` is a risky conversion specifier: you may have a buffer overflow if the file contains a long string before the `,`
- `%[^,]` cannot parse an empty field and you have many such fields in your file
- you do not check the number of conversions returned by `fscanf()` so you do not detect conversion error caused by the first empty field and the next call, returns `0` because the empty field cannot be converted as an integer, causing the loop to exit.
- for more reliable error recovery, you should read the file one line at a time and convert the CSV line, check the result and report failures explicitly
- to parse empty fields, you cannot use `fscanf()`, nor `strtok` and friends, you should instead write custom function to parse number and string fields.

Here is a safer approach, assuming string members of the `Contact` object are all `char` arrays.

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int parse_csv_number(const char **pp, int *dest) {
    char *p = *pp;
    char *end;
    long num;
    errno = 0;
    num = strtol(p, &end, 10);
    if (p == end)
        return 1;  // not a number
    if (errno != 0 || num < INT_MIN || num > INT_MAX)
        return 2;  // number too large
    if (*end == ',')
        end++;
    else
    if (*end != '\0' && *end != '\n')
        return 3;  // extra characters after number
    *dest = num;
    return 0;
}

int parse_csv_string(const char **pp, char *dest, size_t len) {
    char *p = *pp;
    size_t i = 0;
    p += strspn(" \t");  // skip banks
    while (*p != ',' &&*p != '\n' && *p != '\0') {
        if (i + 1 >= len)
            return 1;    // string too long
        dest[i++] = *p++;
    }
    dest[i] = '\0';
    if (*p == ',')
        p++;
    *pp = p;
    return 0;
}

int deserialize(Contact **headp) {
    const char *filename = "contacts.csv";
    char buf[256];
    char *p;
    int count = 0;
    FILE *file = fopen(filename, "rb");

    if (file == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot open %s: %s\n", filename,
                strerror(errno));
        return -1;
    }
    Contact *head = NULL;
    Contact *tail = NULL;
    while (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, file)) {
        Contact *cp = malloc(sizeof(*cp));
        if (cp == NULL) {
             fprintf(stderr, "memory allocation error: %s\n", strerror(errno));
             break;
        }
        p = buf;
        if (parse_csv_number(&p, &cp->id)
        ||  parse_csv_string(&p, cp->firstName, sizeof cp->firstName)
        ||  parse_csv_string(&p, cp->middleName, sizeof cp->middleName)
        ||  parse_csv_string(&p, cp->lastName, sizeof cp->lastName)
        ||  parse_csv_string(&p, cp->phone, sizeof cp->phone)
        ||  parse_csv_string(&p, cp->company, sizeof cp->company)
        ||  parse_csv_string(&p, cp->address, sizeof cp->address)
        ||  parse_csv_string(&p, cp->birthday, sizeof cp->birthday)
        ||  parse_csv_string(&p, cp->website, sizeof cp->website)
        ||  parse_csv_string(&p, cp->note, sizeof cp->note)
        ||  parse_csv_number(&p, &cp->status)
        ||  p[strspn(p, " \t")] != '\n') {
            fprintf(stderr, "invalid CSV line: %s\n" buf);
            continue;
        }
        count++;
        cp->next = NULL;
        if (head == NULL)
            tail = head = cp;
        else
            tail = tail->next = cp;
    }
    *headp = head;
    fclose(file);
    return count;
}
```

If the strings in the `Contact` object are string pointers (`char *`), you must allocate the strings. Here is a modified version:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int parse_csv_number(const char **pp, int *dest) {
    char *p = *pp;
    char *end;
    long num;
    errno = 0;
    num = strtol(p, &end, 10);
    if (p == end)
        return 1;  // not a number
    if (errno != 0 || num < INT_MIN || num > INT_MAX)
        return 2;  // number too large
    if (*end == ',')
        end++;
    else
    if (*end != '\0' && *end != '\n')
        return 3;  // extra characters after number
    *dest = num;
    return 0;
}

int parse_csv_string(const char **pp, char **dest) {
    char *p = *pp;
    char *str;
    size_t i = 0, len;
    p += strspn(" \t");       // skip banks
    len = strcspn(p, ",\n");  // locate end of string
    str = strndup(p, len);
    if (str == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "memory allocation error: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return -1;
    }
    p += len;
    if (*p == ',')
        p++;
    *dest = str;
    return 0;
}

int deserialize(Contact **headp) {
    const char *filename = "contacts.csv";
    char buf[256];
    char *p;
    int count = 0;
    FILE *file = fopen(filename, "rb");

    if (file == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot open %s: %s\n", filename,
                strerror(errno));
        return -1;
    }
    Contact *head = NULL;
    Contact *tail = NULL;
    while (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, file)) {
        Contact *cp = malloc(sizeof(*cp));
        if (cp == NULL) {
             fprintf(stderr, "memory allocation error: %s\n", strerror(errno));
             break;
        }
        p = buf;
        if (parse_csv_number(&p, &cp->id)
        ||  parse_csv_string(&p, &cp->firstName)
        ||  parse_csv_string(&p, &cp->middleName)
        ||  parse_csv_string(&p, &cp->lastName)
        ||  parse_csv_string(&p, &cp->phone)
        ||  parse_csv_string(&p, &cp->company)
        ||  parse_csv_string(&p, &cp->address)
        ||  parse_csv_string(&p, &cp->birthday)
        ||  parse_csv_string(&p, &cp->website)
        ||  parse_csv_string(&p, &cp->note)
        ||  parse_csv_number(&p, &cp->status)
        ||  p[strspn(p, " \t")] != '\n') {
            fprintf(stderr, "invalid CSV line: %s\n" buf);
            continue;
        }
        count++;
        cp->next = NULL;
        if (head == NULL)
            tail = head = cp;
        else
            tail = tail->next = cp;
    }
    *headp = head;
    fclose(file);
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. The hard-coded file name ("contacts.csv") doesn't match the file name you claim "file.csv".  This appears to be an error in your question.
2. You probably don't want to open a text .csv file in binary mode.
3. `fscanf()` returns number of fields matched which in this case 4, and it would not match the last status field. `> 0` is a defective test of success.
4. `%[,]` "Matches a nonempty sequence of characters from the specified set" but you have an empty set so it doesn't match.  You cannot use `fscanf()` to match empty fields.
5. `(*head)->next` is not initialized to an address and quite possibly NULL which would terminate your loop.  After your `malloc()` your array you would have loop through the `.next` pointer to the following entry in the array.  Or just use the array and forget about the linked list:

```
for(size_t i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
   (*head)[i].id ...
}
```

6. Always specify a maximum field when reading strings to avoid buffer overflows.

I suggest you use an existing csv library.

If you need to write a parser yourself then I I suggest you use `fgets()` to read a line from your file then use `strchr()` to find the next separator.  Remember to `strdup()` each field values as the line read would change for each loop iteration.  Here's a sample to get your started:

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define LINE_LEN 100

typedef struct Contact {
    int id;
    char *firstName;
    char *middleName;
    char *lastName;
    char *company;
    char *phone;
    char *address;
    char *birthday;
    char *website;
    char *note;
    int status;
} Contact;

const char *parse_chr(const char *s, char chr) {
    if(*s == chr)
        return s + 1;
    return NULL;
}

const char *parse_int(const char *s, int *d, int fallback) {
    char *next;
    long l = strtol(s, &next, 10);
    if(l > INT_MAX || l < INT_MIN || s == next) {
        *d = fallback;
        return NULL;
    }
    *d = l;
    return next;
}

const char *parse_str(const char *s, char **v, char *fallback) {
    size_t n = strcspn(s, ",");
    if(!n)
        *v = fallback ? strdup(fallback) : fallback;
    else
        *v = strndup(s, n);
    return s + n;
}

#define PARSE_CHR(CHR) \
        next = parse_chr(s, CHR);\
        if(!next)\
            goto err;\
        s = next

#define PARSE_INT(NAME) \
        next = parse_int(s, &(*c)[*n].id, -1);\
        if(next)\
            s = next

#define PARSE_STR(NAME) \
        next = parse_str(s, &(*c)[*n].NAME, NULL);\
        if(next)\
            s = next        

int deserialize(FILE *f, Contact **c, size_t *n) {
    if(!f)
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    for(*c = NULL, *n = 0;; (*n)++) {
        char line[LINE_LEN];
        if(!fgets(line, LINE_LEN, f))
            break;

        Contact *tmp = realloc(*c, (*n + 1) * sizeof **c);
        if(!tmp)
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        *c = tmp;

        const char *s = line;
        const char *next;
        PARSE_INT(id); PARSE_CHR(',');
        PARSE_STR(firstName); PARSE_CHR(',');
        PARSE_STR(middleName); PARSE_CHR(',');
        PARSE_STR(lastName); PARSE_CHR(',');
        PARSE_STR(company); PARSE_CHR(',');
        PARSE_STR(phone);  PARSE_CHR(',');
        PARSE_STR(company); PARSE_CHR(',');
        PARSE_STR(address); PARSE_CHR(',');
        PARSE_STR(birthday); PARSE_CHR(',');
        PARSE_STR(website); PARSE_CHR(',');
        PARSE_STR(note); PARSE_CHR(',');
        PARSE_INT(status); PARSE_CHR('\n');
        continue;
err:
        printf("Could not parse %s\n", line);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

int main() {
    Contact *c;
    size_t n;
    deserialize(fopen("contacts.csv", "r"), &c, &n);
    for(size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf(
            "%d, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %d\n",
            c[i].id,
            c[i].firstName,
            c[i].middleName,
            c[i].lastName,
            c[i].company,
            c[i].phone,
            c[i].address,
            c[i].birthday,
            c[i].website,
            c[i].note,
            c[i].status
        );
        free(c[i].firstName);
        free(c[i].middleName);
        free(c[i].lastName);
        free(c[i].company); 
        free(c[i].phone); 
        free(c[i].address); 
        free(c[i].birthday); 
        free(c[i].website);
        free(c[i].note);
    }
    free(c);
}
```

and example output:

```
4, d, d, d, (null), (null), (null), (null), (null), (null), 0
3, c, c, c, (null), (null), (null), (null), (null), (null), 0
2, b, b, b, (null), (null), (null), (null), (null), (null), 0
1, a, a, a, (null), (null), (null), (null), (null), (null), 0
```

`PARSE_INT()` and `PARSE_STR()` considers their respective field values optional.  `PARSE_CHR()` is required.  The underlying functions support optional values with fallback or required values.